# How to catch mouseout event correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code:

```
<div class='no_translate'>Not translated</div>
```

And following code for mouseover/mouseout events:

```
            $('.no_translate').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).empty();
                var field="<form method='POST' action=''><input name='a' type='textarea'/></form>";
                $(this).html(field);
            });

            $('.no_translate').mouseout(function() {
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).html('Not translated');
            });
```

I want to transform simple text to input field and back. But there is a little problem: when I move my cursor on a new field (don't out from it) then this field transform to simple text and back many times, but I don't out from it and I don't understand what's going on. Please, tell me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSFiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/jZeF6/)**

```
$('.no_translate').hover(function() 
{
    $(this).empty();
    var field="<form method='POST' action=''><input name='a' type='textarea'/></form>";
    $(this).html(field);
},
function() 
{
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).html('Not translated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("element").hover(
  function () {
        hover code
  }, 
  function () {
     hover out code.
  }
);
```

if you steel have problem just jsfiddle your code...

Comment: Please, can you transform my code using hover event? Thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks fedosov you were quick i was just building jsfiddle and snap you did it :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/vvbnE/

**Jquery code:**

```
 $('.no_translate').hover(function() {
                $(this).empty();
                var field="<form method='POST' action=''><input name='a' type='textarea'/></form>";
                $(this).html(field);
 }, function(){
         $(this).empty();
        $(this).html('Not translated');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.no_translate').hover(function() {
        $(this).empty();
        var field="<form method='POST' action=''><input name='a' type='text'/></form>";
        $(this).html(field);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).html('Not translated');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwgLe/2/)